# Should "the" or no article be used in "is ___ principal of this school"?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article, determiners, zero-article

> Q. Mrs. Kanwal is ............ principal of this school.
>
> (1) no article
>
> (2) a
>
> (3) an
>
> (4) the

Some people say that there should be "no article" before the noun "principal". They say the reason is that the noun "principal" has a fixed position in this sentence "this school", so there should be no article.

However, ChatGPT-4 and some books state that the article "the" is right, and most English teachers also give "the" as the right answer.

So please give an answer with reasons as it will be very important for many students.

Please give a strong valid proof for "the" also can be taken as a right answer. For this question I failed a government exam . It will be very helpful if anyone give me a proof.

Comment: Unfortunately, English doesn't work like that. There are no proofs, only established usages. In this case, both 1 and 4 are acceptable.  1 is acceptable for the reason that you have stated, but this reason does not forbid the use of 4, which is the normal situation when you are talking about one specific example of the noun. The question is faulty, because there are two possible correct answers.

Comment: This is a complex question. The grammarian Master put forward the analysis that there are two 'invisible' articles in English, the zero article (most indefinite) and the null article (even more definite than ;the'). 'We had chicken for tea' illustrates the zero article (missing before 'chicken', where 'a' or 'some' are also possible for an unspecified chicken) and 'He was king of all the Northern Lands' illustrates the null article ('the king' is possible here, not 'a king'). Here, the definite ((4)) or the null ((1) in the question's wording, though there is really an invisible article) ...

Comment: may be used;  both are fine.... This is ELU level. See [Why do people sometimes omit the definite article where it seems sensible to include it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/why-do-people-omit-the-definite-article/427204#427204)

Comment: Both 1 and 4 are acceptable. This is similar to usages such as: Rishi Sunak is [the] prime minister of the UK. She is [the] world champion. He is [the] captain of the team, etc, etc.  When you are talking about one person being in a unique position, either *no article* or *the* is possible.

Comment: Please give me a strong valid proof that "the" also be right answer for this question. Because of this question I failed a exam for government job. If I proof that "the" also valid I will pass the exam and I will get the job. So please.

Comment: One of the main uses of the: the is used when there is only one. Schools only have one principal. The Earth revolves around the Sun. Yes?

Comment: [If would be helpful if anyone could give me proof of this.] Was it a civil service exam? There's a great movie on Netflix about that exam and a young man.

Comment: @Lambie No it is a exam for teaching job as a teacher. I think that I will go to court against it so I need proof for this. Because people are divided in to catagory some people say no article and some people say it will be no article and both give there logic as I mentioned.

Comment: Ok, so no article is sometimes *heard*. Nevertheless, one of the rules for the in writing is: if there is only one of a person or thing. A school has only one principal, ergo: the principal.

Comment: @Lambie - so 'he was headmaster of Eton' is always wrong?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Why are you doing this? I explained why there is a the. **I never said that without it is wrong. did I? I repeat: it is heard but if you look at the actual *rules* for the, not written by me, by the way, what I have said about its use is *true*. And I even said this in my answer. I was trying to explain the reasoning behind the Indian government's exam. How would **you explain it?**

Answer (score 0):

Mrs. X is the principal of the school.
Mrs. X is principal of the school.

**Definition and Uses of the Definite Article 'the' in English
Glossary of grammatical and rhetorical terms**

[use of the](https://www.thoughtco.com/definite-article-grammar-1690423)

**Here are the relevant ones for *this* question**:

> "In broad outline, the major uses of the are the following: [...]
>
> 2. for a unique or fixed referent: the Prime Minister, the Lord, the Times, the Suez Canal; [A school principal: there is only one for the
>    school]
>    [...]
> 3. for something which is part of the immediate socio-physical context or generally known: the doorbell, the kettle, the sun, the weather;
>    [...]

A school is very often in the vicinity of the speaker, it is part of the immediate socio-physical context.

However, in the absolute, it is not wrong to leave out the *the*. But the graders of the Indian government exam do not agree. So be it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use "the" in your sentence as you are talking about a school. And, there is usually **one principal** in a school. So, it would be wrong to use the noun without an article.

You can check the explanation [here](https://testbook.com/question-answer/choose-the-appropriate-article-for-the-blank3--5f8960f6d17f89904b3794b9#:%7E:text=Article%20%27the%27%20is%20definite%20and%20is%20used%20to%20specify%20nouns.&text=In%20the%20context%20of%20a,article%20to%20complete%20the%20sentence.) as well.